# How to open text files that have no extensions in python?

Tags: python, path, glob

I have a directory full of article names that have no extension.

I did some reading and found that inputting the full path would lead to python treating the actual text document as a directory rather than a document. So I tried the following:

```
import os
import glob

path = '/Downloads/20061020_20131126_bloomberg_news/2012-07-10/'
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*')):
    print("test")
    file = open(infile, 'r')
    print(file)
```

This doesn't work. Theoretically it should result in about 100 documents printing out. And the test print statement doesn't trigger either.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Use os.listdir() to get all the files in a certain directory. glob may not be returning what you think it is.

Comment: `os.listdir()` or `os.walk()` for certain functionality

Comment: you mean `print(file.read())` right? note that you have to test against files because directories won't open

Comment: "This doesn't work" is not a good description of your problem.  Is your code returning an error? If so, what is the error? Otherwise, how is it behaving currently and what is your expected outcome?

Comment: @Idlehands He told us that it is not working (he probably doesn't know why which is why he opened a question on SO) and he DID give the expected behavior...

Comment: It's returning nothing. Which is why I'm so surprised. I'll try os.listdir()

Comment: So using os.listdir() also did not work initially until I dropped the leading "/" before downloads. Then it starting populating the fields.

Comment: So I can see the files now, but I still can't open a single one. I tried using print(file.read()) instead as well, and it went back to giving me an error that the file/directory didn't exist.

Comment: @a1letterword, do you still happen to have the Bloomberg news corpus that you mention in your post?